# Multiplos Alerts Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, alert

Estou tentando Criar uma resposta padrão  usando os `alerts do bootstrap`,
o meu objetivo com um simples:

```
    $(".alert").addClass('alert-success').text('Configurações salvas com sucesso.');
```

Eu escolho a classe `alert-success` e insiro um texto no alert.

Quando no mesmo botão clico e neste deverá mostrar um `warning` porque a pessoa não preencheu um campo por exemplo eu uso:

```
   $(".alert").addClass('alert-warning').text('Selecione  um Banco/Empresa Por favor.');
```

O 1° problema vem ai, porque a classe `alert-success` ja esta inserida no dom
e nesse caso eu preciso remove-lá assim:

```
 if($(".alert").hasClass('alert-success')){
        $(this).removeClass('alert-success');
 }
```

Verifico se a classe existe e removo.

Então toda vez que eu vou adicionar uma nova mensagem eu tenho que verificar se existe a classe para remove-la.

e por usar o `close` do `alert` ele usa um atributo chamado `data-dismiss`  que remove completamente o elemento. inves dele utilizei o metodo `hide()`.

[Alert Message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13550477/twitter-bootstrap-alert-message-close-and-open-again)

Teria alguma forma de simplificar todo esse processo de alerts ?

```js
$("#success").click(function() {
  if ($(".alert").hasClass('btn-warning')) {
    $(".alert").removeClass('btn-warning');
  }
  $(".alert").toggle().addClass('btn-success');
  $(".alert #resposta").text("This is a Success message!");
});

$("#warning").click(function() {
  $(".alert #resposta").text("This is a Warning message!");
  if ($(".alert").hasClass('btn-success')) {
    $(this).removeClass('btn-success');
  }
  $(".alert").toggle().addClass('btn-warning');
});

$("[data-hide]").on("click", function() {
  $("." + $(this).attr("data-hide")).hide();
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class='btn btn-success' id='success'>success</button>
<br>
<br>
<button class='btn btn-warning' id='warning'>warning</button>
<br>
<br>


<div class="alert text-center" role="alert">
  <a href="#" class="close" data-hide="alert">&times;</a>
  <div id="resposta"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consegui resolver essa questão criando uma função que recebe o alerta exemplo `sucesso`,`atencao`,`erro` e o `texto` e dou um `append` em uma div que eu criei ex: `resposta`, a função se encarrega de eliminar o alerta no `click` e também no `close`, e na alternação dos alertas eu consigo limpar o `alert` usando `empty()`:

```js
   function msg(alerta, texto) {
     var resposta = '';
     $("#resposta").empty();
     if (alerta === 'sucesso') {
       resposta = "<div class='alert btn-success text-center' role='alert'>" +
         "<a href='#' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='Close'>&times;</a>" +
         texto + "</div>";
     } else if (alerta === 'atencao') {
       resposta = "<div class='alert btn-warning text-center' role='alert'>" +
         "<a href='#' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='Close'>&times;</a>" +
         texto + "</div>";
     } else if (alerta === 'erro') {
       resposta = "<div class='alert btn-danger text-center' role='alert'>" +
         "<a href='#' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='Close'>&times;</a>" +
         texto + "</div>";
     }
     $("#resposta").append(resposta);

     $(".alert").click(function() {
       $(".alert").hide();
     });
   }

   $("#success").click(function() {
     msg('sucesso', 'Configuracoes salvas com sucesso.');
   });

   $("#warning").click(function() {
     msg('atencao', 'Preencha o campo XXXX por favor.');
   });
   $("#danger").click(function() {
     msg('erro', 'Error Tem alguma coisa errada que nao esta certa.');
   });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<br>
<br>
<div class="col-xs-4">
  <button class='btn btn-success btn-block' id='success'>success</button>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-4">
  <button class='btn btn-warning btn-block' id='warning'>warning</button>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-4">
  <button class='btn btn-danger btn-block' id='danger'>danger</button>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div id="resposta"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Com certeza tem... existem *n* formas possíveis, mas baseado no seu exemplo, você pode simplesmente fazer assim:

```
function setTextInAlert(classe, message) {
    $('.alert').attr('class', classe);
    $('#resposta').text(message);
}

$(document).ready(function(){

   $('.botao').on('click', function(){

      var id = $(this).attr('id');

       switch(id) {
        case 'msg_01':
          setTextInAlert('alert btn-success text-center', 'Message Success!');
         break;
        case 'msg_02':
          setTextInAlert('alert btn-warning text-center', 'Message Warning!');
         break;
        case 'msg_03':
          setTextInAlert('alert btn-danger text-center', 'Message Danger!');
         break;
       }

   });
});
```

E na sua html:

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class='btn btn-success botao' id="msg_01">success</button>
<br>
<br>
<button class='btn btn-warning botao' id="msg_02">warning</button>
<br>
<br>
<button class='btn btn-danger botao'  id="msg_03">error</button>

<div class="alert text-center" role="alert">
  <a href="#" class="close" data-hide="alert">×</a>
  <div id="resposta"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Também tive esse mesmo problema ao implementar essas mensagens no meu sistema. Porém resolvi  aplicando o `$(this)` antes de seu fechamento.

```
$("#success-alert").fadeTo(3000, 500).slideUp(500, function () {
      $(this).find("#success-alert").alert('close');
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Sei que não é uma resposta direta, mas tenho tido muito sucesso em usar [Bootbox.js](http://bootboxjs.com/).

É bastante útil em casos assim, onde você quer que apareça uma mensagem igual `alert()` mas quer usar o style do bootstrap. O bootbox.js é super-fácil para usar, embora não tenho encontrado documentação em português.

A maior vantagem é porque não precisa de HTML nenhum - cria tudo na hora que precisar.